# Multiple #if statements in Apache Velocity

Tags: velocity

I want to write the following if - else logic in Velocity

```
If $var1 == NONE
   ( If $subvar1 != 'null' 
      return True 
    else 
        return Failed_Sub1)
Else
    If $subvar2 != 'null' 
        return True 
     else 
        return Failed_Sub2
```

So basically $subvar2 is only evaluated if $var != NONE and $subvar1 is only evaluated if $var == NONE

I tried something like

```
#if($var1 != 'NONE')
    #if($subvar2 != 'null')True
    #{else}Failed_Sub2
    #end
#else
    #if($subvar1 != 'null')True
    #{else}Failed_Sub1
    #end
#end
```

But its returning nothing to me. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

Do you want to avoid null values or strings containing 'null'?

In velocity, you can check for nulls using any non assigned reference, for instance `$null` :

```
#if($var1 == $null)
...
```

Otherwise than that, your code looks fine and nested `#if` statements are definitely possible.

[Here](http://velocity.apache.org/engine/2.2/user-guide.html#if-elseif-else)'s the relevant documentation.